# Example Games or Apps that Use GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking for example apps that use Google Cloud Messaging, because I want to ensure it doesn't require a user to login.  I know it requires a google account, but most people have that stored on their android OS.  Does anyone have any example apps that use it that don't require a login screen?

Comment: No GCM apps require a user to log in to run the app or require a login screen. A Google account is only supposed to be required for Android 3.2 and older devices, and then the user only logs in when setting up the account.

Comment: Even on older Androids, users doesn't log in to the app itself - they provide their Google accounts once, typically on first use of the device. From that point on, GCM just works.

Comment: Do you guys have any app examples I can go look at?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, no login is required in an application that uses GCM. As an example you can take the official [GCM Demo application](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java) by Google. In this app, the registration to GCM is done when the app is first launched (or when it's first launched after an update is installed). It doesn't require any login in order to register to GCM.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with GCM registration.
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
    }
}
```